# Generate SQLite Database with Intellij or Maven for Unit tests?

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, intellij-idea

I have written some unit tests for a Java repository called `CountryRepository.java`

These unit tests are configured to use a generated SQLite DB file in the test resources folder like so:

```
 /**
 * This test relies on the test-seed.sql file located in /src/test/java/resources/db/country
 */
public class SqliteCountryRepositoryTest {

    private final static String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:sqlite::resource:db/country/test.db";
```

**File location**

[image]

Since we don't want to commit DB files to git, I have to manually generate the test.db file so that the unit tests work.

e.g.

```
sqlite3 test.db
> .read schema.sql
> .read test-seed.sql
```

How can I configure Maven and/or Intellij to generate this DB file each time I run the tests, so that it will reliably work?

Do I need to write a shell script and call it through Maven?

Bonus points for how I can do the same for the main/resources/db file

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider creating a database in the `setUp` method of the JUnit test using [plain Java code](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/create-database/)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe generating a jUnit ClassRule that on "beforeClass" creates the DB and loads the schema, and on "afterClass" deletes those files would be the best approach for you. This way the files get created only for the test, and you even can generate them on a temp location.
To generate the DB file programatically, it is just a matter of creating a connection. See the link here with some sample code: 
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/create-database/

Comment: Thanks. will this work for inside a JAR though, if it is on the resource path? I thought you cannot write to a file inside a JAR?

Comment: You cannot write a new file inside a JAR, but you can always use the default temp location to do that, e.g. File::createTempFile  ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- )

Comment: Thanks but this is not the solution I require. I need to have the db file generated before runtime and inside the JAR :)